# jQuery UI Themeroller-generated dialog's CSS not working

Tags: css, jquery-ui, themeroller

I put together a page that shows what's happening [here](http://www.eventidewebdesign.com/public/contactFormTest/contact.html). The dialog is a confirmation that an email was sent, so you'll need to fill out the form to get the dialog to pop up. (I wanted to retain as much as the original functionality as possible.)

I generated a UI theme using Themeroller and the dialog I'm using is **completely void** of all styling. To the point that the dialog is completely transparent and all that shows in the dialog is the text in the dialog's div and the unstyled close buttons.

I tried both the compressed and un-compressed UI css and js files with no change.

I'm using some UI effects elsewhere in the same site (highlighting, etc), and they work fine.

Is this an issue with the Themeroller generator or am I missing something?

For now I can just display a label with a confirmation message, but I'd really like to use a dialog.

Comment: It seems that the images (usually used for customization) used by the generated css are in a location where can`t be loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't linked to the jQuery UI css anywhere. Here's a screenshot of the page after I injected the base jQuery UI theme.

[image: Example with jQuery UI CSS linked]

Comment: OMG! I can't believe I missed that!!! Well, that's **my** embarrassing moment of the week (probably the month)! Thanks, ryan.